# Why does didUpdateLocations: only have one location after locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates:

Tags: ios8, cllocationmanager

I have location services working in iOS8.

It is set for `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` to restart when in the background and `startUpdatingLocation` for accuracy.

When I set `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES`, the location services get paused and resumed as expected. However, the following call to `didUpdateLocations:` only has one location in it.

I was expecting to receive a bunch of locations that were received by the OS while the delivery was paused. Am I missing something here? Does it have anything to do with `deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable`?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655389/481207) talks about a post on Apple Dev Forum, but I get nothing when searching for `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically`.

Please note: this issue has nothing to do with calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization` or setting prompts in `info.plist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pause the location updates, the system considers that you don't need the location for now. Resuming it will only give you the current location.
**This is a normal behavior.**

Answer (score 4):

Further to the answer by [Quentin Hayot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30886764/481207)...

The documentation for `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` states:

> Allowing the location manager to pause updates can improve battery life on the target device without sacrificing location data.

This is **highly misleading**.

What it really means is `when location manager pauses it will sacrifice location data: the app does not get and never will get location updates until the location manager resumes`.

It should explain that **paused** location updates are completely different from **deferred** location updates.

To improve battery life, the app should call `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:` which does deliver all location updates gathered while deferring to `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`.

The documentation for `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` states:

> If updates were deferred or if multiple locations arrived before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional entries.

which is reasonably clear, but it could state that it has nothing to do with, and should not be confused with, `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically`.