# How much does pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically affect iBeacon detection?

Tags: ios, performance, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, region-monitoring

Working on Apple's **iBeacons**, here is some code that I use to initialise CLLocationManager and start monitoring for beacon regions:

```
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
    self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
```

How much does **pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically** play a part in region monitoring?

The official documentation says:

> A Boolean value indicating whether the location manager object may
>   pause location updates.

However the "[Getting Started with iBeacons](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/Getting-Started-with-iBeacon.pdf)" official guide does not mention this. Plus it was last updated in 2014 and I haven't found any more on this.

- How does this affect battery life?
- How does this affect the iBeacon region detection?

Comment: Is this discussion of any help to you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17655389/4209778

Answer (score 1):

Location updates and beacon detection are not related.

iBeacon detection uses the Bluetooth chipset and doesn't provide you with a location as such. It just tells you that you entered (or exited) a `CLBeaconRegion`.

`CLCircularRegion` detection is different; this relies on determining the user's latitude and longitude; either by GPS or WiFi. GPS has a significant impact on battery life.

So, the short answer is that `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` shouldn't have any impact on beacon detection.

Answer (score 0):

If you check full description for `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` in documentation, you'll see explanation:

> Allowing the location manager to pause updates can improve battery
>   life on the target device without sacrificing location data. When this
>   property is set to YES, the location manager pauses updates (and
>   powers down the appropriate hardware) at times when the location data
>   is unlikely to change. For example, if the user stops for food while
>   using a navigation app, the location manager might pause updates for a
>   period of time. You can help the determination of when to pause
>   location updates by assigning a value to the activityType property.

And for `activityType`:

> The location manager uses the information in this property as a cue to
>   determine when location updates may be automatically paused. Pausing
>   updates gives the system the opportunity to save power in situations
>   where the user's location is not likely to be changing. For example,
>   if the activity type is CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation and no
>   location changes have occurred recently, the radios might be powered
>   down until movement is detected again.

If you turn on `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` it'll start to monitor significant location changes and save battery since it is not using GPS so often.

Region detection, in such case, will occur when there is significant change, so this check will be performed less often, tricky part here is how much is region detection important for you - if you decide to save battery will significant change detection be ok for region detection.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. If I am designing an app to work with **iBeacons that are dynamically turned on and off** it would be best to leave this flag to false then. In that case I am assuming that it will **fail the detection in case the user is not moving**. **What if I leave it to false and the user is not moving**. Shall I expect it to detect the newly activated beacon if if idle? When I leave it to **false** from my testing, when the device is idle next to the beacon emitting hardware, it seems to have a long long latency (60 minutes+ and only when the user unlocks the screen).

Comment: PS: From my previous knowledge most people seem to say that there is a 15 minutes "grace time" which does not seem to apply when the device is not moving (becomes longer).

Comment: documentation states that significant change should wake the system and your app at least every 15 minutes, even if no location changes have occurred - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Comment: yes. But what is classed as a **significant change** ? Presence of beacon or location? From my observation it seems that the presence of beacon alone is not always sufficient to get a 15 minutes react time when the app is not running.

Comment: did you turned on background mode in project plist?

Comment: Yes. It will eventually work. But as said only after long and irregular times (e.g. 30 min, 60 min + user interaction with screen).