# pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically - setting change by distanceFilter, and activityType

Tags: ios, swift, locationmanager

I would like to know the detailed setting of pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically (when it is true) for Location Manager in swift/xcode.

As far as we checked, the Apple doc is not clearly documented but if `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true`, background GPS tracking stops when Apple judges the GPS tracking is not required. I would like to know the detail. For example;

If we have distanceFilter small, like 10m, does it mean the automatic pausing is less accurate? Or it has nothing with the pausing function?

How is the activityType affecting the automatic pausing? if we want to have longest time to pause, which one is recommended?

If not GPS is updated (GPS accuracy is least) but device itself is shaking? I.e. does the pausing function use gyro, accel sensors?

(Im checking it by myself but was wondering any precedents here....)

Closest topic in stackoverflow I found was below, but no direct answer at all.. [iPhone GPS in background never resumes after pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484352/iphone-gps-in-background-never-resumes-after-pause)

I am not interested to hear other alternatives to achieve what I might want to achieve, but I really want to know the detail of `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically`

Thanks so much!